# What's your favorite JS/CSS drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking to implement one on a website, just curious what everyone else has used and what kind of experiences they've had

**EDIT** I'm also not a huge fan, but the client is insistant and for this case they can click on the "hoverable" part and then get to the same pages in the dropdown from there so basically this will just be a way to get to pages with one less click

Answer (score 5):

I really like the [Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/example/) dropdown menu from [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns).  It's really easy to implement (I've done it myself, and I'm not much of a Web programmer), and even works in IE.

Comment: See also "Son of Suckerfish"
http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/
http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: Anything with "Son of" in the title makes me think of old B-grade horror movies, and so is automatically awesome.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I use the [YUI Menu](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/). It's quite flexible, offers many methods of declaring what's in the list, and is easy to skin.

Answer (score 3):

[Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples) is a jQuery enhancement of Suckerfish and supports several levels of dropdown and various layout options.

It degrades nicely:

- With Javascript and CSS, the dropdowns fade in nicely and the menu has [other enhancements](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started).
- With CSS only, the dropdowns still work (IE6 is supported).
- With neither, the menu degrades to an unordered, nested list.

I am using this now and like it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the on on Steve Gibson's site [grc.com](http://www.grc.com/menudemo.htm). It is purely CSS -- uses no Javascript. It's not all that intuitive, and there are parts that are IE-specific, but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking out superfish which expands slightly on suckerfish

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [mygosuMenu](http://code.gosu.pl/).
from the page:
- horizontal or vertical menu
- can be positioned statically or absolutely
- delay for showing/hiding menu (can be turned off by setting to 0)
- position of submenus can be changed, so they can for example overflow parent elements
- on the same page there can be many menus created
- seperated into 3 layers: behaviour(javascript), structure(html), presentation(css)
- search engine friendly
- free for any use (BSD license)

Answer (score -2):

I don't like them, tend to avoid them as much as possible.