# create vertical menu with css

Tags: html, css

[image]

how can i create menu like this.???

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you searched for `css menu`? I am sure there are a lot tutorials.

Comment: I suspect people would appreciate you having an attempt at it yourself, instead of going for a 'gimme the codez' approach.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421708/whats-your-favorite-js-css-drop-down-menu and http://message.uk.com/dropdown-menus-no-thanks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard, all-CSS solution is [suckerfish or son of suckerfish dropdowns](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/).

Answer (score 0):

Go have a read of this (admittedly somewhat dated) [article on A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/).